# Factor Completely.

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Again, this question if from my final practice exam.

Factor Completely.
$$81x^4-256y^4$$

I'm able to get this far, How do I know which of the two factors should be factored further.
$$(9x^2+16y^2)(9x^2-16y^2)$$

Answer Key: $$(3x-2y)(3x+2y)(9x^2+4y^2)$$

Comment: The one that is a difference of squares is always factorable.

Comment: (a+b)*(a-b) = a^2 - b^2

Comment: So, the Answer is $$(3x-2y)(3x+2y)(9x^2+16y^2)?$$

Comment: The answer key is not correct.

Comment: The key is wrong, it should be $(3x-4y)(3x+4y)(9x^2+16x^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A difference of squares is always factorable into two binomial factors. This immediately tells you that $9x^2 - 16y^2$ can be factored further.

A sum of squares cannot be factored into two binomials, and in your case $9x^2 + 16y^2$ has no common factor to pull out, nor can it be factored in any other way.

As Lubin points out below, there are sums of squares that are factorable, however, so a sum of squares should not be immediately discounted as not factorable.

Comment: Does that mean that the answer key is wrong?

Comment: Yes it is. You should use the difference of squares formula for the $9x^2 - 16y^2$ factor, and you must leave the other factor as it is.

Comment: The answer key is wrong. However, it’s not *quite* true that the sum of two squares is unfactorable. Consider $x^4+4$ which certainly is a sum of two squares, yet is equal to $(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$

Comment: @Lubin Good point. Thanks for mentioning.